# ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

**I encounter the following error while running an Expo Project on an iOS device. Metro has encountered an error: SHA-1 for file /Users/user/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/console.js (/Users/user/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/console.js) is not computed . How do I solve this?**

ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /Users/birfatura/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/console.js (/Users/birfatura/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/console.js) is not computed.
Potential causes:
1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.